# Invertir las vocales de una palabra con SQL

Tags: sql-server

Me han propuesto un ejercicio en el que tengo que invertir las vocales de una palabra cualquiera. Olvidaos de tildes, mayúsculas, etc, solo vocales sin más. Lo he hecho en Excel con fórmulas 365 y he seguido la misma lógica para hacerlo con SQL. Me ha funcionado, pero quizá pueda reducirse considerablemente.

Os dejo mi código:

```
declare @word varchar(max)=
    'esternocleidomastoideo'
;with serie(n) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select n+1 from serie where n<100
), chars(n,c) as (
    select top(len(@word))
    n,substring(@word,n,1)
   from serie
), mxb(n,c,b) as (
    select n,c, iif(c in ('a','e','i','o','u'),1,0)
    from chars
), s2(i,a) as (
     select 0,0
     union all
     select 
     iif((select b from mxb where n=a)=1,i+1,i),a+1
     from s2 where a<=len(@word)
)
select string_agg(r,'')Resultado from (
select iif(b=1,
        substring(reverse((select string_agg(c,'') from mxb where b=1)),
        (select i from s2 where n=a-1 ),1),
        substring(@word,n,1))r
from mxb
)t
```

El resultado sería este:

> osternicloadomisteodee

Es la misma palabra con las vocales invertidas.

¿Alguna sugerencia para reducir código?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos empezar por cambiar la forma en la que generas la serie (o tabla de números) puesto que usar una función recursiva puede generar problemas de rendimiento. Para eso podemos usar una serie de CTEs en cascada.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT -- Asignamos los números
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT *
FROM cteTally;
```

Teniendo esta plantilla, podemos empezar a modificar. Usamos los números para separar por letra y a cada letra la identificamos como vocal o no. También les asignamos un orden a cada vocal, tanto en sentido ascendente como descendente. Por último, reemplazamos las vocales mediante un `LEFT JOIN` a la misma tabla uniendo por el tipo de letra y si es consonante usamos el mismo orden, pero si es vocal se usa el orden contra el orden inverso.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS( -- 10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( -- 10 x 10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( -- 100 x 100 = 10,000 filas (suficiente para varchar(8000))
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP( LEN(@word)) --Limitamos el número de filas
        -- Asignamos los números
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
),
cteString AS(
    SELECT n, 
           SUBSTRING( @word, n, 1) letra,
           IIF( SUBSTRING( @word, n, 1) LIKE '[aeiou]', 1, 0) es_vocal,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IIF( SUBSTRING( @word, n, 1) LIKE '[aeiou]', 1, 0) ORDER BY n) orden,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY IIF( SUBSTRING( @word, n, 1) LIKE '[aeiou]', 1, 0) ORDER BY n DESC) orden_inv
    FROM cteTally
)
SELECT STRING_AGG( v.letra, '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.n)
FROM cteString c
JOIN cteString v ON c.orden    = IIF( c.es_vocal = 1, v.orden_inv, v.orden) 
                AND c.es_vocal = v.es_vocal
```

Se podría factorizar un poco más, pero espero que así quede suficientemente claro.

Comment: Muy buena Luis. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Dudo que se pueda simplificar mucho más, pero la que te dejo, es una forma más tradicional y tal vez más comprensible: un doble ciclo cruzado para rearmar la palabra.

```
DECLARE @Palabra    VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @NewPalabra VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @c          VARCHAR 
DECLARE @c_r        VARCHAR 
DECLARE @i_asc      INT
DECLARE @i_desc     INT

SET @Palabra    = 'esternocleidomastoideo'
SET @NewPalabra = ''
SET @i_asc      = 1
SET @i_desc     = LEN(@Palabra)

WHILE @i_asc <= LEN(@Palabra)
BEGIN
    SET @c = SUBSTRING(@Palabra, @i_asc, 1)
    IF @c IN ('a','e','i','o','u') BEGIN
        WHILE @i_desc > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @c_r = SUBSTRING(@Palabra, @i_desc, 1)
            SET @i_desc = @i_desc - 1
            IF @c_r IN ('a','e','i','o','u') BEGIN
                SET @NewPalabra = @NewPalabra + @c_r
                BREAK
            END
        END
    END ELSE BEGIN
        SET @NewPalabra = @NewPalabra + @c
    END
    SET @i_asc = @i_asc + 1
END

SELECT  @Palabra,
        @NewPalabra
```

Comment: Es buena tu solución, pero buscaba una que solo valorara código SQL. Tomo nota igualmente, me ha gustado. Gracias.